# Any modification necessary to web api project web.config when web api project is created as a web application under an asp.net web site?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web site which runs on port 443 which is https. I also have a asp.net web api which also needs to run on port 443. Because of that, I decided to create a new web application under asp.net web site. I also created a new application pool for that. The problem is that when I try to run web api project, I keep getting configuration file errors. For example it says Default Connection is already added since asp.net web site web.config adds Default Connection already before web api project does. Are there any special steps to take in order to make this work?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to incorporate both site and api projects web config files into one web config file?

Comment: web.configs inherit from their parent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178685(v=vs.100).aspx